# Change android device physical resolution

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-spica

I have downloaded an app that, when it starts, check the device resolution and displays a message indicating that my resolution should be at least be 800x600. I have changed my screen density using the LCD Resolution app in order to have a fake 800x600 resolution (it worked well).

Problem is that the app still disaplys the error message and displays my resolution has if it hadn't change so I guess it is based on the physical resolution of the device. Is there a way to fake the physical resolution so that I can run the app?

Comment: The LCD density is not the same as the resolution, no matter what the app description says.  It would be fairly involved to fake this -- I think you'd need to run this app inside another app or an emulation layer or something in order to scale everything down for your actual screen size.  I highly suspect nothing like that currently exists.

Comment: It is really strange that it requires so high resolution considering that most of phones are still 800x480 or less. Which is the name of the app your trying to run?

Comment: It is the Pokerstars app (not sure it is available on market, but here anyway: http://www.pokerstars.fr/en/mobile/).

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

Your device uses a screen resolution of 320 x 480 pixels, while the application you're trying to run needs a minimum of 800 x 480 pixeis.

While you are using an application to manipulate the Screen Density, this can't overcome the physical limitation of your device's screen, that the application checks for before running.

In short, you can't run the application on that device.

---

## Elaborating the Answer

### Your Device

Your device, the [Samsung I5700 Galaxy Spica](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i5700_galaxy_spica-2965.php) uses 320 x 480 pixels of screen resolution.

### PokerStars Mobile Game

The application you've mentioned in the question comments, under the [FAQ](http://www.pokerstars.fr/en/mobile/faq/) section says:

> **Does PokerStars Mobile Poker work on all Android devices?**
>
> No. PokerStars Mobile Poker is designed only for mobile devices running Android™ 2.2 and above, with a minimum screen resolution of 800x480. Compatible devices include (but are not limited to):
>
> - Samsung Galaxy
> - Galaxy Nexus
> - Motorola Droid RAZR
> - HTC Sensation
> - HTC Desire
> - Sony Ericsson Xperia X10
> - Sony Ericsson Xperia X13
> - Acer Liquid A1

### What is Screen Resolution?

Quoted from Android Developers - [Terms and Concepts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms)

> The total number of physical pixels on a screen. When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work directly with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size and density groups.

- Screen Size

  > Actual physical size, measured as the screen's diagonal.
  >
  > For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen sizes into four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and extra large.
- Screen Density

  > The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch). For example, a "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.
  >
  > For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen densities into four generalized densities: low, medium, high, and extra high.